# How do you redicrect your Java application to another java file

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
public class Cyptography implements ActionListener {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cyptography");

  JTextField input = new JTextField();
  JButton decrypt = new JButton("decrypt");
  JTextField output = new JTextField();
  JButton encrypt = new JButton("encrypt");
  Container north = new Container();

  JRadioButton Scytale = new JRadioButton("Scytale");
  JRadioButton CaesarCipher = new JRadioButton("Caesar Cipher");
  JRadioButton VigenereCipher = new JRadioButton("Vigenere Cipher");
  Container south = new Container();

  public Cyptography() {
    frame = new JFrame("Cyptography");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setSize(700,300);

    north.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
    north.add(decrypt);
    north.add(input);
    input.addActionListener(this);
    north.add(encrypt);
    north.add(output);
    output.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    south.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    south.add(Scytale);
    Scytale.addActionListener(this);
    south.add(CaesarCipher);
    CaesarCipher.addActionListener(this);
    south.add(VigenereCipher);
    VigenereCipher.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Cyptography();
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource().equals(Scytale)){
      //redirects to Scytale


    }
    else if (event.getSource().equals(CaesarCipher)){
      //redirects to Ceasar Cipher

    }
    else if (event.getSource().equals(VigenereCipher)){
      //redirects to Vigenere Cipher
    }
  }

  //decrypt - a text that has been decoded.
  public void decrypt() {

  }

  //encrypt - convert (information or data) into a cipher or code, especially to prevent unauthorized access
  public void encrypt() {

  }
}
```

These three (Scytale, Caesar Cipher, and Vigenere Cipher) buttons are Radio Buttons. This is what I'm trying to get: I was to click onto a radio button, then I want the method actionPreformed to direct to another java class. called Scytale.java or CaesarCipher.java or VigenereCipher.java.

Comment: This code does not seem relevant to your question. Your question is pretty general.

Comment: Trying to get? All I see is a barebones UI with zero logic implementation

Comment: I am sorry I'm still kind of new to Java

Comment: There are plenty of resources online easily found by googling your cipher words. Stack overflow isn't a code writing service nor is it a replacement for traditional learning.

Comment: This is not about whether you're new to the language; this is about asking an actual question. "I want the program to direct to another java file." does not tell us what you want to do. Are you trying to call a method on another class? Are you trying to start another program? Even if you don't know the Java terms like "method" and "Java", you can describe things in specific terms -- "I want to run some code in another Java module in the same program" or something. Try again.